# Our build got rejected by Google Play store multiple times due to complaint issue of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES. How can we overcome this issue?

Tags: installation, request, package

Google play store team mentioned that they found **our app is not compliant with how REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.**

But no where in our app, we have used REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission but still it was rejected multiple times.

We have added below code snippet in android manifest to remove the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES from our build and sent for play store review. We have verified in the build permissions and could n't find REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES but, still it was rejected by play store.

Please let us know if anyone faced this issue and how can we rectify this error and make our build approved by Play store team.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was related to the open_file in Flutter. This package is using REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in the manifest.

I fixed by using (open_file_safe) :https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_safe

or you can also use open_filex: https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex

both packages are the same as open_file, but .apk file type is not supported. Thus, android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission is not required.

If you are not using the open_file plugin, you check if the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES is declared in the merged manifest in build/app/intermediates/merged_manifest/ If it is being used remove the permission or else remove that plugin and find any other alternative to that plugin.

Note: If you are facing this issue with a native android project You may be querying all packages with the package manager, this is no longer allowed since Android 8.0. To resolve open the android project of your app in android studio and check the Merged Manifests portion of the AndroidManifest.xml to see if you find that permission is being used in your app if it is being used remove the permission.

If you are still not able to find the plugin or in the merged manifest file so for workaround you can try adding :

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

In your main manifest file. try submitting the app again on the play store hope it will help.

See more info here. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12085295?hl=en

Github Issue: https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/204

Answer (score 0):

Check your builds in Alpha, Beta and open testing tracks. Sometimes builds in production will be rejected if your other tracks have this permissions. So remove the old builds in these tracks and try to upload the newer APK to prodcution track.